# popViewControllerAnimated animation is not working

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

I know this is kind of repetitive question in SO, but I'm still unable to figure it out. The animation is not working when the app goes to background and then comes back up. The first time the app launchs I'm able to get the push/pop animation between the views, but once the app goes to background, it stops animating anymore.

I have created a custom navigation controller class extending `UINavigationController` and written the `popViewControllerAnimated` method in it.

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIViewController* viewController = [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];    
    UIViewController* nextViewControler = [[self viewControllers] lastObject];
    [nextViewControler viewWillAppear:animated];    
    [viewController viewWillDisappear:animated];
    return viewController;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

This happens if somewhere in your code you are either forcing a call to one of the `viewWillAppear` counterparts with `YES` or `NO` instead of letting iOS decide, or if you mismatch calls to `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` with `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 6):

On my end it was missing call `[super viewDidAppear:animated]` in my UITabBarController.

It actually produced some other strange behavior, so I'd recommend to always call `[super viewWill/Did*]` methods

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try just using the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol to cause viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear to be called.  For more details see:

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UINavigationController/viewWillAppear.html

Comment: There is absolutely not required to implement the protocol methods. From my above code you can see I'm already calling viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear in the method from my extended navigation controller class.